# How to find list of words (in thousands) in list of tsv files (hundreds), with output as number of match for each string in each file, in linux?

Tags: linux, csv, count, grep, match

I have hundreds of tsv file with following structure (example):

```
GH1 123 family1
GH2 23 family2
.
.
.
GH4 45 family4
GH6 34 family6
```

And i have a text file with list of words (thousands):

```
GH1
GH2
GH3
.
.
.
GH1000
```

I want to get output which contain number of each words occurred in each file like this

```
 GH1 GH2 GH3 ... GH1000
filename1 1 1 0... 4
.
.
.
filename2 2 3 1... 0
```

I try this code but it gives me zero only

```
for file in *.tsv; do
    echo $file >> output.tsv
    cat fore.txt | while read line; do
        awk -F "\\t" '{print $1}' $file | grep -wc $line >>output.tsv
        echo "\\t">>output.tsv;
    done ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script.

Just put sdtout to output.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
    echo -n "$p "
done <words.txt

echo ""
for file in *.tsv; do
    echo -n "$file = "
    while read p; do
        COUNT=$(sed 's/$p/$p\n/g' $file | grep -c "$p")
        echo -n "$COUNT     "   
    done <words.txt
    echo ""
done
```

Comment: That's horribly inefficient.

Comment: Whats the complexity you are offering?

Comment: This code also produces tabular format output bu the output results are zero, means no match for the words in tsv file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Awk script which collects a list like the one you describe.

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "\t" }
    NR==FNR { a[$1] = n = FNR;
        printf "\t%s", $1; next }
    FNR==1 {
        if(f) { printf "%s", f;
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                printf "\t%s", 0+b[i] }
        printf "\n"
        delete b
        f = FILENAME }
    $1 in a { b[$1]++ }' fore.txt *.tsv /etc/motd
```

To avoid repeating the big block in `END`, we add a short sentinel file at the end whose only purpose is to supply a file after the last whose counts will not be reported.

The shell's `while read` loop is slow and inefficient and somewhat error-prone (you basically always want `read -r` and handling incomplete text files is hairy); in addition, the brute-force method will require reading the word file once per iteration, which incurs a heavy I/O penalty.

Comment: Hi, i tried this code, it gives the result in tabular format but count result are zero for all.

Comment: Does your input file have DOS carriage returns? Take them out and try again. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings